# How to use an external command to modify selected words and lines?

Tags: shell-command

Something I've found useful in other editors is the ability to:

- take the selected text
- run an external command and pass the selection to its `stdin`
- take the external commands `stdout` and replace the current selection with it.

*This way you can write useful text tools which operate on the selection using any language that can do basic io.*

How can this be done with emacs using the selection?
... a single character, word, paragraph... etc.

(Directly in the command line, or via a key binding?)

---

### Note

The reason I'm asking this question is because I would like to operate on the selection. (i.e., the text that would be removed if `x` was pressed).
In evil-mode `!sort` for example only works on a line-level.

Comment: [`shell-command-on-region`](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/executing-shell-commands-emacs).

Comment: @Dan: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function
[`shell-command-on-region`](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/executing-shell-commands-emacs) to
pipe some text into an external command.  For example, the
following simple command will give you a word count of the active
region by sending the selected text to the shell command `wc`:

```el
(defun wc-region (beg end)
  "Count words in the active region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (if (region-active-p)
      (shell-command-on-region beg end "wc -w")
    (message "No active region")))
```

You can adapt other members of the `shell-command` family as
necessary if you're not interested in using the region (e.g., if
you'd like to use `thing-at-point`).

Comment: The OP asks for replacing the selected text with shell command output, you could show the use of the *replace* arg to `shell-command-on-region` for that.

Comment: The replace selected region by the stdout of the shell command operating on it (what Dan and Jean-Pierre describe in Code) is mapped to ```C-u M-|``` in the standard key map.

Comment: This doesn't replace the selection.