# How to send a string to the SQLi (sql-mode/sql-interactive-mode) buffer after processing?

Tags: sql-mode, sql-interactive-mode

How can I send a selected region in the sql-mode buffer to an external shell command and let the result be displayed in the sql-interactive-mode buffer (REPL)?

For example, normally, if I select a region in the sql-mode buffer (e.g. `my_table`) and hit `C-c C-r`, the text in the region is sent to the sql-interactive-mode buffer (REPL area) and evaluated as a SQL statement (which will generate an error since `my_table` isn't a valid statement).

Can I alter this behavior so that, the text is first sent to a unix shell command as input, and then the output of shell command is collected and displayed in the interactive-mode buffer?

The shell command I have in mind [is this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338000):

```
{ read message; psql -c "\\d+ $message"; }
```

The closest thing I can find is [this emacs.SE example](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30270),

```
(defun wc-region (beg end)
  "Count words in the active region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (if (region-active-p)
      (shell-command-on-region beg end "wc -w")
    (message "No active region")))
```

which sends the select text to the Unix shell that does something (a word count) on it, and shows the result in a buffer called "Shell Command Output".

But I'd like to have it work in a sql-mode buffer, and have the processed result displayed in the sql-interactive-mode buffer (REPL area) instead of a new buffer. Just as if I had sent a SQL statement to the REPL.

I adapted the example above to:

```
(defun wc-region (beg end)
  "Count words in the active region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (if (region-active-p)
      (shell-command-on-region beg end " { read message; psql -c \"\\d+ $message\"; }  ")
    (message "No active region")))
```

which almost works except it's not sending output of the unix command to sql-interactive-mode buffer. Instead, it creates a new buffer for output.

Ultimately, I want to select a table name in SQL-mode, and display its definition in the sql-interactive-mode buffer by hitting a shortcut key. But I don't know elisp well enough.

-- Update --

@phils

Thanks a lot for your answer. I have two more very basic questions:

1. can the shell `command` be fixed so that it doesn't have to be keyed in? The following command seems to work (with the second version):

   ```
    { read s; echo "\\d+ $s"; }
   ```

Is there a way to fix `command` to the above string in a wrapper function or using `setq` somehow?

2. After executing the command, the focus is in the sql-mode, how can I automatically switch the focus to the sql-interactive-mode buffer after the command is issued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at any of the definitions of the `sql-send-*` commands, you'll see they all hand off to `sql-send-string`.  E.g.:

```el
(defun sql-send-region (start end)
  "Send a region to the SQL process."
  (interactive "r")
  (sql-send-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
```

`shell-command-on-region` is a good place to look for how to obtain a string to pass to `sql-send-string`.  That uses `call-process-region` behind the scenes, so a simple (will not handle errors) combination of the two could look like this:

```el
(defun my-sql-send-region-via-shell-command (command start end)
  "Send a region to the SQL process via shell COMMAND."
  (interactive
   (list (read-shell-command "Shell command on region: ")
         (region-beginning)
         (region-end)))
  (let* ((buf (current-buffer))
         (sql (with-temp-buffer
                (let ((tmpbuf (current-buffer)))
                  (with-current-buffer buf
                    (call-process-region
                     start end shell-file-name nil tmpbuf
                     nil shell-command-switch command))
                  (buffer-string)))))
    (sql-send-string sql)))
```

or perhaps this:

```el
(defun my-sql-send-region-via-shell-command (command start end)
  "Send a region to the SQL process via shell COMMAND."
  (interactive
   (list (read-shell-command "Shell command on region: ")
         (region-beginning)
         (region-end)))
  (let ((temp-buffer-show-function
         (lambda (buf)
           (sql-send-string (with-current-buffer buf (buffer-string)))
           (kill-buffer buf))))
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer "sql")
      (call-process-region
       start end shell-file-name nil standard-output
       nil shell-command-switch command))))
```

Entering `cat` as the shell command ought to give the same outcome as `sql-send-region`.

---

> Is there a way to fix `command` in a wrapper function?

Sure, you just need to read the `start` and `end` and then pass them along with a hard-coded `command`.

```el
(defun my-sql-send-region-via-FOO (start end)
  "Send a region to the SQL process via shell command FOO."
  (interactive "r")
  (my-sql-send-region-via-shell-command "FOO" start end))
```

You could also make `start` and `end` optional, and have the main function figure them out when they're not passed.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

> how can I automatically switch the focus to the `sql-interactive-mode` buffer after the command is issued?

It looks like `sql-send-string` supports that directly; try adding `(sql-pop-to-buffer-after-send-region t)` to the outermost `let` bindings.